# how to find and replace files from .gitignore in bash

Tags: git, bash, replace, grep

i only found how to find strings in files but how can I replace commented lines and how exectly should i replace them?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo enter file name 
read fname 
exec<$fname 

while read line 
do
    echo $line; 
done
```

Comment: It'll be pretty complicated - most likely you'll end up using sed and/or awk. Proper way is to implement that in any common scripting language.

Comment: It is way from clear, what you are trying to accomplish. Please edit your answer to better describe the problem. You want to read the `.gitignore` file, and then do what with the contents ?

Comment: I want  to replace all files that have ignored extension

Comment: Replace with what? Can you include an example of what your `.gitignore` file looks like before, and how you would like it to appear after, your modifications?

Comment: for example:
`*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe`
i want to find all files in my repo that have this extensions. And then replace them to /var/tempdir

Answer (score 0):

In order to move the files whose names match patterns give in `.gitignore`, try the following loop:

```
while read pattern; do
   echo mv $pattern /var/tempdir
done < .gitignore
```

If the output of this loop looks like the correct list of commands, remove the word "echo" and run the loop again to actually move the files.

Comment: This is not likely to work with patterns like `/*.log` or `!somefile`... probably a number of others, as well...

Comment: Very good point, @twalberg. This code should probably be considered a script generator, whose output should be manually reviewed and edited, rather than a script itself.